Error at execution : initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
I'm using JavaFx which i have downloaded at https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/
I can compilate my code by using this command : javac -d bin --module-path lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml src/model/dao/.java src/model/data/.java src/controller/.java src/view/.java
However, when I want to execute with the following command :
java -cp bin;view --module-path "..\lib\javafx" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics view.Main 

I got the following error :
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:268)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1082)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1082)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:280)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:410)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
        ... 5 more

For your information, that's why I obtain when I type java -version :
java version "17.0.8" 2023-07-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211, mixed mode, sharing)

I've also tried to download several versions of JavaFX (17.0.11, 22.0.11) but I still got this error.
I've also used several terminals like Powershell and the Command prompt.
By the way, I have tried to run it on Eclipse and that's working.
I know that several users submited this question on the forum but I didn't find any reponse that fix my problem.
If someone have an idea for a solution, I'd be glad to let me know.
If you need more details don't hesitate to tell me.

I think that i've find the problem.
I've put the entire folder "openjfx-17.0.11_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-17.0.11\lib" in my project directory and thats work.
So now, my command to execute is : java --module-path "openjfx-17.0.11_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-17.0.11\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml view.Main
I think that the problem of the execution is from the name.
Hope than can help someone if he need.

A "No toolkit found" error typically means the native code of JavaFX is missing entirely, included incorrectly, or for a different platform than the current host. In a JavaFX SDK, the native code is not embedded in the JAR files as a resource, but rather is placed "next" to JAR files (on Windows, they're the bin/*.dll files). Most likely you only copied the JAR files. By instead copying the entire SDK folder into your project, you are also copying the shared native libraries.

The command given in this answer is pretty much the same as the command given in the openjfx.io getting started instructions section "Run HelloWorld using the JavaFX SDK", which is for windows:  java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX with ,javafx.fxml appended to the --add-modules switch as noted in the getting started instructions when FXML is also used.  The getting started instructions also contain information on using build tools, IDEs and creating runtime images for JavaFX apps.
